# What's the meaning of "the business into one the leaders" in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

I found this sentence in Cambridge Dictionary and I'm having hard time understanding it.

> He succeeded in building the business into one the leaders in its field.

I can know the slight meaning, or what the author wants to say, but I want to know the exact meaning. Can anyone help to find the meaning? I don't know what "the leaders" should be related to.

Comment: There's an error in that sentence. It should read: "*He succeeded in building the business into one **of** the leaders in its field.*" Does that help you understand it better?

Comment: Oh yes! Now I got it if it has 'of' in it. It helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on an error in a dictionary

Comment: @leo Great find! I've notified them of the error. Hopefully they'll fix it

Comment: @leo Just got this email from Cambridge University Press: *"Thank you for reporting this issue with the example on the definition of Succeed. Customer feedback is important to us for product development. Our editorial team has advised that you are correct and that this will be amended in a future update."* Congrats to you!

Answer (score 0):

If we break it down we get

> field = The type of business, eg "making semiconductors" or "banking" are two fields.

> the leaders in its field = The most successful businesses, among that type of business.

> One of the leaders = Means not the leader, but a member of the top group.

> build (something) into.... = grow the company and change it

As noted in a comment, your quote has omitted the word "of" in the phrase "one of".